# How to check the element in object Ionic 4

Tags: typescript, ionic4

I am using Ionic 4.  I post the data to my API then I get the return result like this:

```
{
    "responses": [
        {
            "Detection": {
                "Images": [
                    {"url":"https:URL"}, 
                ],
                "Ages": [
                    {"age":"33"}, 
                ],
                "Labels":[
                    {"label":"game"}
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But sometimes the 'Ages" is not returned. So, my question is how can I check the element in return object from API? For example, I want to check is the response has return  **"Ages[]"** or not? How can I write the condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can access like this;

> here is [working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kuhhrr?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```
data={
    "responses": [
        {
            "Detection": {
                "Images": [
                    {"url":"https:URL"}, 
                ],
                "Ages": [
                    {"age":"33"}, 
                ],
                "Labels":[
                    {"label":"game"}
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}

this.data.responses[0].Detection.Ages[0].age
console.log("Age :",his.data.responses[0].Detection.Ages[0].age);
```

//check ages presents

```
let ages=this.data.responses[0].Detection.Ages

 if(ages.length)
 {
   console.log("Age object present :",ages.length);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If your project is running the recently released TypeScript 3.7 then you can use the new [Optional Chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining) feature.

It lets you use `?.` to chain it together, and if one of the elements doesn't exist then instead of an error it just returns undefined.

This would let you write something like:

```
let firstAge = this.data.responses[0].Detection?.Ages?.[0].age;
```

Which would result in either `33` in your example json, or `undefined` if it didn't exist.